# There are how many ways to lock in c

Tags: c

I am quite a newbie to c programming. Until now i only found `pthread_mutex_lock` can make the code region run only by one thread. Does there are any other ways to implement a lock? Or every other way to do a lock is still use `pthread_mutex_lock` function?

Comment: `pthreads` isn't C. If you're asking about multi-threading and pthreads, then reading up a bit on them first might be in order.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Threads were only introduced into the ISO C standard with C11, a rather recent edition to the standard so not necessarily *widely* supported yet.

You need to look into `threads.h` and the `mtx_*` functions for an understanding of that.

Before then, `pthreads` was probably your best bet with its wide implementation although, not being standard C <sup>(a)</sup>, its support wasn't mandated.

For example, Windows has its own way of doing threading, using functions like `CreateThread`.

However, there are various third-party products such as [pthreads-win32](http://sourceware.org/pthreads-win32/) that aim to give pthreads support to Windows, to assist in porting of applications from POSIX-compliant operating systems.

---

<sup>(a)</sup> It *is* a POSIX standard (part of IEEE 1003.1) so that may be good enough for some people.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to lock in the `c` language. Operating systems might provide support for locking (without regard for the language), and libraries such as `pthreads` can take advantage of operating system services, however this is beside the language. (By contast, other languages have native locking built into them, such as through Java's `synchronized` keyword.)

Comment: You may want to look into C11 and then rethink that first sentence :-)

Comment: I understand your point however I would argue that this is not a c language feature, it's a specification for a library to be provided with certain compilers. Unless a feature is something the compiler is actively aware of, it's just a library which may or may not be present and/or supported by the underlying operating system. Regardless, I'm glad you commented because I was unaware of C11 and it looks interesting!

Comment: There is _one_ current C standard, which specifies the language proper _and_ the libraries that come with it. Freestanding environments aside, you don't get the option to provide less than the full library if you want to comply with the standard, so your comment about it being provided with "certain compilers" is irrelevant - those compilers that don't provide it cannot be C compilers (again, discounting the freestanding environments such as in the embedded arena). Mutithreading (and mutexes/locks) are part of that.